# Frequency of script

Tags: powershell

I am trying to create a powershell script which is based on csv file for metadata, I have defined a column `Frequency` with a number in it.

for example :

```
PageName FrequencyMonths  Email
Page1       3             security@company.com
Page2       6             HR@company.com
```

I want to know a way that my powershell runs the code whenever the next frequency date is.

The script I have takes input from csv with above like information and runs a a scheduled task "Daily" to send emails to above people at the.

I want to schedule my PS script to run daily however send email only after 3 months to the security team (every after 3 months) and every 6 months to the HR team

Please suggest

Expected result is to send mails to respective teams based on the frequency of months - using a daily running windows scheduled task

Comment: What i have so far :
$csv = import-csv "$path"

foreach ($Row in $csv)
{

$PagenName = ($row).PageName
$Frequency = ($row).FrequencyMonths
$OwnerEmail = ($row).OwnerEmail

######$emaildate = (get-date).AddMonths($Frequency)
}

Comment: Please [edit] your question. Code in comments is unreadable.

Comment: You probably don't want to run this daily if you only need to send email at most once a month? you can save some sanity checking by just running it on the first of every month.

Answer (score 0):

Your current script sets `$EmailDate` to today + x Month. But everytime the script is run and without saving the value anywhere... You should create another column with the date of the next execution.

```
If( (get-date).date -le $row.NewColumn ){
# sent the mail
# replace $row.NewColumn with (get-date).Date.AddMonths($Frequency)
}
```

when you are done export the csv to replace the old one.